# How to copy/assign a CompositeKey into another CompositeKey in hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, composite-key

I try running a map reduce on some data on a cluster and get the following output.

```
0000000000  44137 0 2
1   1
902996760100000 44137 2 6
2   2
9029967602  44137 2 8
2   2
90299676030000  44137 2 1
9029967604  44137 2 5
2   2
905000  38704 2 1
9050000001  38702 2 24
2   2
9050000001  38704 2 14
2   2
9050000001  38705 2 12
2   2
9050000001  38706 2 13
2   2
9050000001  38714 2 24
2   2
9050000002  38704 2 12
2   2
9050000002  38706 2 12
2   2
9050000011  38704 2 6
2   2
9050000011  38706 2 12
2   2
9050000021  38702 2 12
2   2
9050000031  38704 2 6
2   2
9050000031  38705 2 6
2   2
9050000031  38714 2 12
2   2
```

This is my reducer

```
public class RTopLoc extends Reducer<CompositeKey, IntWritable, Text, Text> {
    private static int number = 0;
    private static CompositeKey lastCK;
    private static Text lastLac = new Text();

    @Override
    public void reduce(CompositeKey key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        int sum = sumValues(values);
        String str = Integer.toString(sum);
        String str2 = Integer.toString(number);
        String str3 = key.getSecond().toString();
        context.write(key.getFirst(), new Text(str3 + " " + str2 + " " + str));
        context.write(lastCK.getFirst(), lastCK.getSecond());
        if(number == 0){
            number = sum;
            lastCK = new CompositeKey(key.getFirst().toString(), key.getSecond().toString());
            context.write(new Text("1"), new Text("1"));
        }
        else if(lastCK.getFirst().equals(key.getFirst()) && sum > number){
            lastCK = new CompositeKey(key.getFirst().toString(), key.getSecond().toString());
            context.write(new Text("2"), new Text("2"));
        }
        else if(!lastCK.getFirst().equals(key.getFirst())){
//            context.write(lastCK.getFirst(), lastCK.getSecond());
            context.write(new Text("3"), new Text("3"));
            number = sum;
            lastCK = new CompositeKey(key.getFirst().toString(), key.getSecond().toString());
        }
    }
```

From what I understand the problem is that hadoop treats lastCK and key as the same object and this condition

```
if(lastCK.getFirst().equals(key.getFirst())
```

will always be true

This is my CompositeKey class

```
public class CompositeKey implements WritableComparable {
    private Text first = null;
    private Text second = null;
    public CompositeKey() {
    }
    public CompositeKey(Text first, Text second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    //...getters and setters
    public Text getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(Text first) {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        setFirst(new Text(first));
    }

    public Text getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(Text second) {
        this.second = second;
    }

    public void setSecond(String second) {
        setSecond(new Text(second));
    }

    public void write(DataOutput d) throws IOException {
        first.write(d);
        second.write(d);
    }

    public void readFields(DataInput di) throws IOException {
        if (first == null) {
            first = new Text();
        }
        if (second == null) {
            second = new Text();
        }
        first.readFields(di);
        second.readFields(di);
    }
    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        CompositeKey other = (CompositeKey) obj;
        int cmp = first.compareTo(other.getFirst());
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
        return second.compareTo(other.getSecond());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        CompositeKey other = (CompositeKey)obj;
        return first.equals(other.getFirst());
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return first.hashCode();
    }
}
```

I tried changing setters to something along this lines

```
public void setFirst(Text first) {
        this.first.set(first);
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        setFirst(new Text(first));
    }
```

where set is [Hadoop Text Documentation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.7/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.java#Text.set%28java.lang.String%29)

but got

```
Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at task.SecondarySort.CompositeKey.setFirst(CompositeKey.java:29)
        at task.SecondarySort.CompositeKey.setFirst(CompositeKey.java:33)
```

How do I make hadoop treat lastCK and key as different objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change these lines:

```
private Text first = null;
private Text second = null;
```

to

```
private Text first = new Text();
private Text second = new Text();
```

And then use:

```
public void setFirst(Text first) {
    this.first.set(first);
}
```

It should work. You could also create `first` and `second` in the constructors.

Comment: It helped, but now I get **java.lang.NullPointerException** when calling **getFirst()** and **getSecond()**

Comment: The object you're calling `getFirst()` on isnt initialized. Where is the error occurring, in your reduce method or elsewhere?